# When does a terminated app receive an APNS silent push?

Tags: ios8, apple-push-notifications, ios9

## APNS Silent push

The Apple Push Notification Service features *silent pushes*, which are received and processed by the app in the background, without any audio or visual alert to the user.

Such push messages are marked with the `content-available=True` argument, and lack the `sound` or `alert` arguments.

## The problem - *some* push not received after reboot or manual termination

When I send a silent push to my app - regardless if it's in the foreground or in the background - it is received and processed as expected.

However, if I terminate the app manually (pressing the iPhone button and swiping it up) it sometimes stops responding to the silent pushes. When the iOS device is rebooted, the same phenomena happens - some silent pushes are not processed by the application. I have some guesses about the reasons and circumstances in which this happens, and I wanted to know if I missed some official Apple guideline here.

## Details

If these pushes have a numeric badge, it is changed in the app icon, so I know that the push messages do arrive to the device. However, the operating system does not deliver the message to the app.

**Under what circumstances does an app running on iOS 8/9 receive and process APNS silent push messages after it has been manually terminated or the device has been rebooted?**

Comment: I'm also facing this - did you ever find satisfactory answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can register remote notifications with an Action on iOS8 or newer, see [Actionable Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26).

Above iOS 7, there is a new feature called Background Fetch, using this feature, you can schedule regular updates of your application even if your application is in the background. See [iOS Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Comment: Yes, iOS will "wake up" but not launch your app to do some work.